# Blocking socket performance vs. non-blocking socket

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I need to write a C++ program to receive udp packets from 2 different NIC at high rate - about 45MB/s per socket (single socket per NIC on the same computer).

I started by creating an event-based socket (using WSAEventSelect) but I'm wondering: does this type of socket model (event-based) may imply some performane penalty ? (since events will be triggered at a high rate and therfore OS may cause some latency)
If I choose blocking socket will I reduce latency ?
Is it true to say that at high throughput blocking sockets may outperform non-blocking sockets ?

Note: Scalability is not an issue since we deal with no more than two sockets.

Thanks,

A.C.

Answer (score 3):

If you have only two sockets, why *wouldn't* you use blocking calls? They have slightly less overhead than any asynchronous socket API and have a simpler programming model. Blocking sockets use async IO under the covers, but they block in the Windows kernel on an event.

You should probably spin up `CpuCount/2` reader threads per socket. Although less threads will perform better if they are able to handle the load (depends on your app). Fewer threads means having a small cache footprint and less context switching.

If you care about cross-socket load-balancing a lot you should probably use IO Completion Ports which are the standard and best-performing way on Windows to perform async IO.

What about latency? Blocking calls will have almost the same latency as "event-based" sockets in your case because there are multiple threads per socket waiting in line on an event to accept the next packet that the NIC receives. With a callback-based async IO approach the latency increases slightly. I expect the difference to be very minimal. The kernel does not introduce any latency. It does not wait for clock interrupts to unblock threads for example. Unblocking happens immediately.

Comment: Exactly right, though I'd even be inclined to say that blocking calls have noticeably less latency, not just "almost the same", even with only a single blocking thread per socket (though the thread might do processing other than just receiving, so a few extra threads are no mistake). The datagrams go into the receive buffer as the NIC fires an interrupt either way, and with blocking API one saves the overhead of queueing (and unqueueing) APCs and bookkeeping OVERLAPPED structures.

Comment: In case like me you didn't know, APC=Asynchronous Procedure Call, NIC=Network Interface Card